# Display innerHTML of child

Tags: javascript

i have:

```
<td id="td1">
     <div>
          aaaaaa
     </div>
</td>
```

how can i get the innerHTML of the child of "td1" ?

```
function displaymessage() {
    var i = 0;
    alert(document.getElementById("td1").childNodes[0].innerHTML);
}
```

dosen't work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Some browsers interpret a line break as the first `childNode`. So you can do:

```
document.getElementById("td1").childNodes[1].innerHTML
```

or a safer method

```
document.getElementById("td1").getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML
```

[**edit 2019**]
or more modern

```
document.querySelector("td1 > div").innerHTML
```

Answer (score 1):

I hate to be the guy that uses jQuery to solve every DOM selection/manipulation problem, but if you used [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) all you would need is...

```
function displayMessage() {
    alert($('#td1 > div').html())
}
```

Comment: While the other answers are technically correct, it's one of those things.  You have to decide if you are or aren't going to use jQuery.  If you are, then it just doesn't make sense *not* to use @Chris W's answer...

Answer (score 0):

try with alert(document.getElementById("td1").childNodes[1].innerHTML);

Answer (score 0):

few browser considered whitespace as text node and that create a problem while traversing.

to avoid that you should check the node type

```
childNode = document.getElementById("td1").childNodes[0]
if(childNode.nodeType==1)
alert(childNode.innerHTML)
```

see more information [here](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodes_navigate.asp)