# Get text node value in DOM

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I'm new to DOM. I want to get the text of the first node with tag **title** in this xml file http://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml , which is **Everyday Italian**. The answer should be this:

```
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

From what I see,

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]
```

Gets the first title node from an array consisting all nodes of title tag.  And if I want to get the text of that node, Shouldn't it be like this?

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].nodeValue
```

Why does it have something to do with childNodes ? And what type is this?

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text content behaves as a `childNode` in this case.  It may be that a line break or other character is causing this to happen. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5753895/2798367), for example)

Either way you can access the content as follows:

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].textContent;
```

I tried `innerHTML` and `childNodes[0]` but neither worked - only the above worked for me.

Source: [Node.textContent - Mozilla WebDocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_nodes_get.asp -

'In the DOM, everything is a node. Element nodes do not have a text value.
The text value of an element node is stored in a child node. This node is called a text node.'

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0] // first title element node
```

So, .childNodes[0] is required to access its text node which is where the text value is stored

Comment: I tried `childNodes[0]` and just got the value `text` (which was not much use!)