# Multiple script tags in HTML are not executing sequentially

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, mutation-observers

**PLEASE VIEW THE RESULT OF CODE SNIPPET IN FULL PAGE**

I'm trying to fetch the **text contents** from a set of nested HTML elements that apparently are *appended at runtime* by a script/API.

---

> Please note that `quote_text` & `children[j]` are elements appended at
>   **runtime** by API/script. hence it is not in my control directly. (I found them out using **inspect element**) So I am trying to change
>   them using javascript as they are not in my control directly.

However, it happens to be that even though the script/API which is responsible for appending the *styled quote* HAS CONTENTS IN IT, it is shown BLANK when tried to set its contents to another div using a script

Why is this happening and how do I go about achieving this?

The reason for me to do this is, I do not want the format style given by API. Rather I want it styled in my way.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}


/******* QUOTE *********************************************************/

.center_bottom {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: -20px;
}

a {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}

.quote_div2 {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="1.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://theysaidso.com/gadgets/v3/theysaidso.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <!-- PART1 -->
    <!-- DIV1: This below script fetches a Quote & displays it in styled fashion -->
    <div id="quote_div" class="tso_simple_borders center_bottom q-t">
      <script id="sc1">
        TheySaidSo.render({
          qod_category: 'inspire'
        });
        //document.getElementById("quote_div").style.display = "none";
      </script>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <!-- PART2 -->
    <!-- DIV2: This is division where i want to paste the plain text from DIV1-->
    <div class="quote_div2">
      <span id="spn"></span>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <!-- PART3 -->
    <!-- In this script, I'm trying to fetch Quote contents and set it onto other div -->
    <script>
      var txt = "This text should be replaced by ONLY TEXT CONTENTS of below quote";
      var qttxt = document.getElementsByClassName("quote_text");
      Array.from(qttxt).forEach((el) => {
        var children = el.childNodes;
        if (el.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'span') {
          el.style.color = "white";
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
          if (children[j].nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'a') {
            txt = txt + children[j].innerHTML;
          }
        }
      });

      document.getElementById("spn").innerHTML = txt;
    </script>

  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

---

**

> for those who are confused about `quote_text`, It is appended at
>   backend(Please check the image below for reference):

**
[image]

---

> The problem seems to be in the **sequence of execution** of scripts.
>   For it to work, the PART1 script should first finish executing and
>   rendering the Quote Box, and after that PART3 script should execute.
>   But it seems to be that BEFORE PART1 even finishes executing, PART3 is
>   executed!! (Which shouldn't happen)

Comment: can you please describe which element is resulting empty ?

Comment: @DupinderSingh, in the script, `txt` variable is empty and hence `<span id="spn">` is empty. `children[j].innerHTML` is the quote shown in the page below inside the white box. `txt` should have take the contents of below quote(int white box)

Comment: Your query is element `quote_text` `var qttxt = document.getElementsByClassName("quote_text");` but I doesn't able to find the element `quote_text`

Comment: @DupinderSingh, `quote_text` is the element appended by the API/script in `DIV1` at **runtime**. So I don't have control of it before runtime. I found that out using right-click-->inspect element in browser

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display innerHTML of child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753817/display-innerhtml-of-child)

Comment: @Kanad, No. There's no problem with the retrieval of nested elements. The problem is that the sequence of execution of scripts is not maintained. According to sequence, first `DIV1`(i.e. the quote in white box) should be rendered from backend, and then only The script to fetch nested elements should be executed. But that doesn't seem to happen. It seems to me that even before the `DIV1` script finishes execution, *the script to fetch its contents* is executed.

Comment: "But it seems to be that BEFORE PART1 even finishes executing, PART3 is executed!! (Which shouldn't happen)". Not exactly. PART 1 creates a new script element to insert the quote, and ends. The new script loads asynchronously and therefore may end up running either before or after PART 3 does. If you can't just override the styling you are given, the general way to deal with this situation is to use a [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: @Alohci, I learnt about `MutationObserver` and tried setting a **callback** using it, but even that didn't suppose to work. perhaps I'm not able to implement it properly. for this example, could you please insert a snippet using Mutation Observer that does the task so as to manipulate the **`<a target="_blank">` tag shown in image above** that asynchronously alters the behaviour of that `<a>` tag after it has finished loading the contents?